# Upload & Pass .csv to Executable in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, executable

I am building a Node js app and I need to run a .exe executable file from the app and pass a user-uploaded .csv file to that executable. Does anyone know how to go about doing so?

I have been playing with:

```js
var exec = require('child_process').execFile;

var fun =function(){
   console.log("fun() start");
   exec('HelloJithin.exe', function(err, data) {  
        console.log(err)
        console.log(data.toString());                       
    });  
}
fun();
```

But I can not figure out how to pass in the .csv as an argument from the UI -> API -> executable

Answer (score 0):

1. To read a uploaded csv file in express and it will get stored into tmp/csv/ path

Ref here : https://www.techighness.com/post/node-expressjs-endpoint-to-upload-and-process-csv-file/

2. Pass the file path as a input (or) read the entire string and pass it as second argument [inside double quotes] while invoking the .exe file 
   In the exe file read the file contents from the path mentioned.